# Examples and graphs of functions that are once, twice, three times differentiable, etc.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to deepen my understanding of differentiation and this idea of infinitely differentiable functions as being "smooth" -- i.e., the more a function is differentiable, the smoother it gets.

I saw the plot of a function that was everywhere continuous but nowhere differentiable, and it looked really...hairy...

Anyway, to help me understand this concept of "smoothness" intuitively, I was hoping someone could give me examples (and hopefully plots, too) of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that are:

a) differentiable only once with continuous derivative (an a plot to see smoothness)

b) differentiable only twice (and a plot for smoothness)

c) differentiable 10 times (and a plot for smoothness)

d) infinitely differentiable (and a plot for smoothness)

Comment: It is not possible to distinguish visually between a say $5$ times but not $6$ times differentiable function and an infinitely differentiable function.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Darn.  Then I dislike saying the more differentiable a function is, the more smooth it is.  I thought these descriptions of differentiability were literal, as a lot of things in math are.  I especially thought this because the function that was continuous everywhere but differentiable no where was absolutely not smooth (it was really scraggly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as soon as a function has a continuous first derivative (or higher derivatives), you won't really be able to tell the difference between different degrees of differentiability by looking at graphs. If you don't believe me, take more and more antiderivatives of $f(x) = |x|$ and compare the plots to see if any of them look any more "smooth" than any others.

Comment: Then what's the point of saying that a function gets more smooth the more differentiable it is?

Comment: @user46944 It's a mathematical statement, not a visual one. If you take the 2nd antiderivative of $|x|$ then it will have a continuous 2nd derivative but not a continuous 3rd derivative. But it's very hard to tell the difference by looking at plots.

Comment: Is there any intuition you can offer on differentiability of functions?

Comment: "Smooth" (infinitely differentiable) functions have very nice properties, like in complex analysis infinitely (complex) differentiable functions can always be defined in terms of power series that converge in some non-trivial radius, and they can even be extended to smooth functions beyond the radius of series convergence using some tricks.

Answer (score 1):

Example of once-differentiable:
$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2 sign(x)}{2}
$$
Its derivative is everywhere continuous $|x|$, but it's not differentiable at $x=0$.